# Changing a recursive method to iterative

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having trouble converting this recursive method (recP) to one which uses loops (itP).

```
public class Main {

    public static int recP(int n) {

        if (n <= 2)
            return 1;
        else
            return (recP(n - 3) * recP(n - 1)) + 1;

    }

    public static int itP(int n) {

        if (n <= 2)
            return 1;
        else
            //do something


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Main.recP(6)); //returns 9
        System.out.println(Main.itP(6)); //should return 9

    }
```

--

If I was to do this by hand, calculating recP(6) using the recursive formula, I'd list out the steps of working and fill in missing details as I went along:

```
P6 = (P3 X P5)+ 1 = (2 X 4) + 1 = 9
P3 = (P0 X P2) + 1 = 2
P5 = (P2 X P4) + 1 = (1 X P4) + 1 = 4
P4 = (P1 X P3) + 1 = (1 X 2) + 1 = 3
```

--

I know that a loop should go in the else part of the method, but I've no idea how that loop will work. Can't figure out a formula for calculating recP/itP.
Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Why do you have *absolutely no idea* how this would work? Can you restate the problem in English? What have you tried?

Comment: Respectfully, unless the English you and I speak is different, I think I've adequately explained that I'm trying to rewrite the recursive method recP() as an iterative method which I've started as itP(). I'm confused as to how I would go about writing a loop which returns the same value, but doesn't use any form of recursion.

Comment: My bad, I meant to ask you to describe the *solution* in English. If you had to calculate it by had using nothing more than a pencil and paper, what would you do?

Comment: Ah okay, I shall post that in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "remember" the three most recent values you calculated and use them to calculate the current:

```
public static int itP(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    int n3 = 1;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n1 = 1;

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        int m = n3 * n1 + 1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        n3 = m;
    }
    return n3;
}
```

Comment: It was obviously a homework assignment... this is what I was trying to steer towards without actually doing the homework for them.

Comment: No, it wasn't a homework assignment, but rather an exercise from a book where solutions hadn't been provided. That said you are completely correct, that guidance and hints are better.